# tabitem not showing on xml file

Tags: tabs, fragment, android-tablayout, tabitem

when I add tab item to xml file (in tabLayout) the design section blank

before I add, after I add tabItem

before
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GuBT.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkC6R.png)

I tried create tabs in fragment booking

Answer (score 0):

not an android expert here, but aren't you missing the id?

Comment: the id is not the problem. there is some render problem I cant fix, but I used viewpager2 and it fixed that( I generated the tab Item through the code)